# OCaml for statement error

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to `OCaml` and when I try to compile my program it says:

> Error: Syntax error
>
> Command exited with code 2.

This error comes after the second `if` statement. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
let rec the_last_game (jugadores : jugador list) (length : int) (mazo : string list) : unit =

 if (juego_acabado jugadores mazo) then begin
    let s = ordenar jugadores in
    imprimir_resultado_final s;
 end
 else begin
    let lista = [] in
    for i = 1 to length do
        let jugadorn = at jugadores i in
        let t = elegir (at jugadores i) in
        let jugadorn = remover_carta_jugador jugadorn (second_tupla t) in
        let jugadorn = top mazo jugadorn in
        let mazo = remover_primera mazo in
        if (es_especial (second_tupla t)) then begin
            let x = especiales (jugador , mazo) carta in
            let mazo = dar_mazo x in
            let jugadorn = dar_jugador x in
        end
        let lista = list_append lista jugadorn in
        let s = append_tuplas s t in
    done;
 end
 let y = dar_ganador_ronda(s (auxdar_ganador_ronda s)) in
 imprimir_ganador(s , (auxdar_ganador_ronda s));
 let lista = aux_aumentar_puntuacion lista y in
 the_last_game lista length mazo;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out some details you have this near the second if:

```
if ... then begin ... end
let lista = ...
```

So, the first line here is one expression (of type unit) and the second line is the beginning of a second expression. If you want to have two expressions executed one after the other, you need a semicolon between them.

Later you have

```
let jugador = ... in
end
```

This is also syntactically invalid. At the very least you need something after `in`.

Generally speaking you need to be careful to use `let` statements that look like this: `let var = expr1 in expr2` and you need to use a semicolon after a unit expression that's being executed for its effect (i.e., an imperative expression).

I hope this at least gets you a little further. OCaml is different enough that it takes some getting used to.

Comment: I couldn't understand the let statement, your explanation was very useful, I think I've solved the previous error, but now in the following step, just outside the for statement, I'm getting an unbound value error.
Modified code: http://pastebin.com/x9tnb2qe

Comment: Reading your code on the link you gave, I have one question. Do you have a formation in OCaml where you have to create a card game ? Because it looks like all of you don't have the basics needed. For example, you think you can write `if b then let a = 3;` and then a will be visible outside. First of all, this is wrong in quite every language, second, this is functional programming so values are persistent (if you write `let x = 3 in let y = 4 in x + y` you didn't modify `x` nor `y`). Read the basics, please. Or ask your teacher.